# Is there a way to avoid Android Textview scrambling when the string is too large?

Tags: android, textview

I've been working on an e-reader that uses an android `TextView` to marquee the chapter of an epub across the screen. This works great when chapters have fewer than ~2300 characters (not common), but starts to scramble my text when chapters are longer. The result looks like this: [image of scrambled chapter text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNW8M.png). Here you can see the beginning of my string overlapping with the middle of my string

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScrollTextView extends TextView {

    // scrolling feature
    private Scroller mSlr;

    // milliseconds for a round of scrolling
    private int mRndDuration = 250;

    // the X offset when paused
    private int mXPaused = 0;

    // whether it's being paused
    private boolean mPaused = true;

    /*
     * constructor
     */
    public ScrollTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    /*
     * constructor
     */
    public ScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    /*
     * constructor
     */
    public ScrollTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // customize the TextView
        setSingleLine();
        setEllipsize(null);
        setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     * begin to scroll the text from the original position
     */
    public void startScroll() {
        // begin from the very right side
        mXPaused = -1 * getWidth();
        // assume it's paused
        mPaused = true;
        resumeScroll();
    }

    /**
     * resume the scroll from the pausing point
     */
    public void resumeScroll() {

        if (!mPaused) {
            return;
        }

        // Do not know why it would not scroll sometimes
        // if setHorizontallyScrolling is called in constructor.
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);

        // use LinearInterpolator for steady scrolling
        mSlr = new Scroller(this.getContext(), new LinearInterpolator());
        setScroller(mSlr);

        int scrollingLen = calculateScrollingLen();
        int distance = scrollingLen - (getWidth() + mXPaused);
        int duration = (new Double(mRndDuration * distance * 1.00000
                / scrollingLen)).intValue();

        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        mSlr.startScroll(mXPaused, 0, distance, 0, duration);
        mPaused = false;
    }

    /**
     * calculate the scrolling length of the text in pixel
     *
     * @return the scrolling length in pixels
     */
    private int calculateScrollingLen() {
        TextPaint tp = getPaint();
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        String strTxt = getText().toString();
        tp.getTextBounds(strTxt, 0, strTxt.length(), rect);
        int scrollingLen = rect.width() + getWidth();
        rect = null;
        return scrollingLen;
    }

    /**
     * pause scrolling the text
     */
    public void pauseScroll() {
        if (null == mSlr) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPaused) {
            return;
        }

        mPaused = true;

        // abortAnimation sets the current X to be the final X,
        // and sets isFinished to be true
        // so current position shall be saved
        mXPaused = mSlr.getCurrX();

        mSlr.abortAnimation();
    }

    /*
     * override the computeScroll to restart scrolling when finished so as that
     * the text is scrolled forever
     */
    @Override
    public void computeScroll() {
        super.computeScroll();

        if (null == mSlr) {
            return;
        }

        if (mSlr.isFinished() && (!mPaused)) {
            this.startScroll();
        }
    }

    public int getRndDuration() {
        return mRndDuration;
    }

    public void setRndDuration(int duration) {
        this.mRndDuration = duration;
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return mPaused;
    }
}
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated. I'm curious if this is just a poor use of Android TextView and maybe I should be using OpenGL instead.

update1: Increasing text size makes the scrambling start sooner. Decreasing it does the opposite.

Update2: String scrambles after it scrolls for ~2300 characters when the font is 32pt

Update3: To clarify [this is what it looks like while it's scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpYMg.gif)

Comment: you can increase the width of textview

Comment: You could put your TextView in a ScrollView, wouldn't that work?

Comment: @jiteshmohite do you mean the layout_width parameter or setting maxwidth to a larger value?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Your long text goes here..." />
</ScrollView>
```

OR you may also use `setText()` if you need to set texts dynamically-

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText("Your long text goes here...");
```

Comment: I've just implemented you suggestion and unfortunately the behavior persists. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @Dustin It's working for me you can try it completely replacing your code. If you need any special property then please mention it.
If you want this text to be scrolled horizontally you can try 'HorizontalScrollView' instead of 'ScrollView' in my solution.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I've just tried HorizontalScrollView as you suggested, but the issue persists. When I initially start the auto-scroll the text looks great. It is later in the book chapter that the text begins to jumble. I just added a video of the behavior in an edit to the original post.

Comment: Is it a real device or emulator? If it's in emulator i suggest you to test it in the real device. Also try in different API level to understand that it's device specific issue or not.

Comment: I've been developing with a real device. I'll look into different API levels tonight and report back. Thanks for the suggestion.